# Google Cloud App Engine PHP 7.2 implement Storge

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am starting using GCloud and have a simple question related to work with App Engine and Cloud Storage.

My PHP application runs over a framework that need a tmp directory, and I try to implement that deploying with tmp folder, in composer.json -> scripts -> try to create a new one and setup permissions, but it shows a read-only file system errors. Also tried to create a symbolic link to /tmp, nothing works.

Understood that I missed some concept, maybe there is a way to map a file system folder to a storage instance (bucket)?

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

You are telling us that you tried to implement something but you are not showing us what did you actually tried.

Did you try to write files into a /tmp directory (no need to deploy a /tmp folder with your code, App Engine have one with read/write policy by default) as stated in the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/using-temp-files)?

Also, Google Cloud Storage is not based on an instance (VM) architecture so asking about "storage instance" is inaccurate.

If writing to a /tmp directory doesn't work for you, sharing with us the code that you tried to implement would be useful.

You can always [write your files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/using-cloud-storage) to a Cloud Storage Bucket by using the [sample code](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-php) provided in the public documentation:

```
function upload_object($bucketName, $objectName, $source)
{
    $storage = new StorageClient();
    $file = fopen($source, 'r');
    $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
    $object = $bucket->upload($file, [
        'name' => $objectName
    ]);
    printf('Uploaded %s to gs://%s/%s' . PHP_EOL, basename($source), $bucketName, $objectName);
}
```